# Check the data quality in Google Sheets (asking for suggestions)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-quality

I'm trying to create a sheet to check the data quality from a survey in Google Sheets the document have this format:

[image]

So basically I was using this formula `=COUNTIF(B2:F2,"Don't know")` to count `Don't know`, empty spaces, 0's and numbers > than 9, if the percentage from the counts is bigger than 0.31 or 31% the data quality is not good, as an example I'll take `row 2`, it has responses from Column B-F (5 cells) and this is the total number of responses, the count of bad data is 2, so in percentage will be represented the quality as `2/5 = 40%`, but I want to do the same for the all survey questions in a survey with 1600 questions, [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SylcKsNjuA9WJ6aCiD1YuORWHfJidlAl3umthylGwuE/edit?usp=sharing),the document attached contains a small piece of data from the original survey. So I would like to ask for a better solution that counting all the columns and the rows, I'm asking for a recomendation or how I should check the data quality, basically in the document I have all the formulas that I need but I would like to have all the formulas in just one. Also in the document in the desirable output column there is the final result that I would like to have. Hoping my explanaiton was good about the desired output.

Comment: Can you please add another column to right and show your desired output to that column manually. We will try to make formula for you.

Comment: Could you also **please** use fullstops, sentences and Capital letters in your question? It is extremely painful to read.

Comment: @Harun24hr Yeah so the desired output depends on the Don't knows and the empty spaces if there are more don't know's and empty spaces the data quality is bad if the data is compleated with a lot of yes and no's the data quality is good

Comment: Your goal is doable, but this question is currently unanswerable. The example file now has Quality ratings per form _response_, but your question seems to specify (…`B15:B21`…) rating form _questions_. It also uses a scale of Good, Not to (sic) good, and Bad without specifying ranges used. You also say empty rows "should be added to the quality analysis" but neither show examples nor explain how. Please edit the example file to make the ratings **exactly match** what you need, and edit the question to explain both how the ratings are determined and how "missing data" factors in, numerically.

Comment: @JoelReid To top on your comment, the OP says *"contains a small piece of data from a survey with **1600 columns**"*. Of course he means rows.

Comment: @marikamitsos I added more information and more formulas to the document

Comment: @JoelReid I edited the post check it again please

Comment: everyone check the formulas in the document please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
=byrow(B2:F,lambda(z,if(offset(index(z,,1),0,-1)="",,
      let(x,(countif(z,"Don't Know")+countblank(z)+--(index(z,,5)=0)+--(index(z,,5)>9))/columns(z),
      if(x>0.3,"Bad","Good")&" Quality"))))
```

[image]

if you wish to see the score alongside the quality status then use:

```
=byrow(B2:F,lambda(z,if(offset(index(z,,1),0,-1)="",,let(x,(countif(z,"Don't Know")+countblank(z)+--(index(z,,5)=0)+--(index(z,,5)>9))/columns(z),{to_percent(x),if(x>0.3,"Bad","Good")&" Quality"}))))
```

Comment: Actually I think this is my formula that I need just check the Google sheets document to check the real data and the output that I have with your formula please I need help to modify your formula https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SylcKsNjuA9WJ6aCiD1YuORWHfJidlAl3umthylGwuE/edit#gid=113434135

Comment: Also when I modify B2 gives me an error

Comment: Check the real data sheet and the formula sheet with the changes

Comment: sure... will check on it. also you seem to be commenting on the sheet but it only has view access

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SylcKsNjuA9WJ6aCiD1YuORWHfJidlAl3umthylGwuE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Now you can edit

Comment: `Column DF` has data in the style of `76-99%`,`100% (all)` and so on. however the condition check for this specific column (Count bigger than 100) is  ">100". hoping you could shed some light on this?!

Comment: I delete that column no worries

Comment: Updated formula in `A2` cell. All % numbers tallied with expected score.

Comment: Thank you so from there I can edit to any other analysis right?

Comment: yes sure as long as the setup and the conditional parameters are same and all

Comment: And how it will be without counting the 0? I'm trying to delete the 0 counts

Comment: you mean the `0` count used for columns `DD:DE`?!

Comment: Yes and also >20

Comment: Just replace the `0` in this part here `countif(index(z,,107):index(z,,108),0)` to `">20"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear everything in ranges `G2:J21` and `L2:M21`

You can now try the following 2 formulas in cells `G2` and `L2` respectively.
*As for column `K2`, it becomes obsolete since it is a fixed number (number 5) that is easily incorporated within the 2nd formula*

in cell `G2` try

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A21="",,
          {BYROW(B2:F21,LAMBDA(zz,{COUNTIF(zz,"Don't know"),COUNTBLANK(zz)})),
           BYROW(F2:F21,LAMBDA(xx,{COUNTIF(xx, 0),COUNTIF(xx, ">9")}))}))
```

in cell `L2` try

```
={INDEX(IF(A2:A21="",,
            LET(vv,BYROW(G2:J21,LAMBDA(ww,SUM(ww)/5)),
               {vv,INDEX(IF((vv<= 0.3),"Good Quality",IF(vv>0.31,"Bad Quality",)))})))}
```

[image]

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

Comment: Have you tried the given formulas? I believe they are quite easy to adjust.

Comment: Just be cautious. I checked the results given by the accepted formula and they seem to deviate form both your manual results as well as the ones given by my formulas. BTW both your way and my formulas give the same results. I would suggest you test thoroughly.